# Probability that a bird is shot down out of n birds

Tags: probability

Assume we have $n$ birds and $10$ hunters. A hunter chooses a bird randomly and independently shoots it down with a probability of $0.6$

*(Note that hunters can choose and shoot at the same bird).*

I want to find the probability that the $i$-th  bird is shot down.

$P(i$-th bird is shot down by some  hunter$) = 1 - P(i-$th bird is not shot down by all hunters$) = 1 - (1 - P($all hunters shoot down bird $i))$

This gives us $P(i$-th bird is shot down$) = 1 - 1 - (\frac{1}{n} \cdot 0.6)^{10}$

However, I don't think this is correct because logically it should be $P(i$-th bird is shot down$) = 1 - (1 - \frac{1}{n} \cdot 0.6)^{10}$

Where did I go wrong in breaking down the probabilities?

Comment: Do the hunters hunt in sequence (e.g. one shoots, then the next shoots a bird not yet shot, etc.) or all at once (e.g. they all aim at a random bird, some of them maybe even at the same bird, and fire, hitting with some probability)? There are other errors here, but the answer you expect only applies to one of these cases.

Comment: We can assume that the hunters all aim at a random bird and then shoot at the same time. So yes they some hunters can aim at the same bird. And some birds might not be aimed at entirely.

Comment: @inquisitivemongoose: What Milo was pointing you to was the fact that if hunters shoot sequentially, some birds would not be available for the later hunters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P(bird is not shot down by all hunters) does not equal 1-P(all hunters shoot down bird). It equals P(all hunters fail to hit bird) which leads to your correct finall formula.

Comment: Could you elaborate why $P($bird is not shot down by all hunters$) \neq 1-P($all hunters shoot down bird$)$?

Comment: @inquisitivemongoose Because the birds are all identical.

Comment: The previous line is looking for the chance of being hit, which is 1 minus the chance of everyone missing.  Everyone missing plus everyone hitting doesn't add up to 1.

Comment: Thanks I got it!